# Fade In Animation with ImageView

Tags: android

I want to animate an image from left to right. How can I achieve that? I have already tried many ways but nothing is working. Here is the code I have tried.

anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="3000"/>
</set>
```

Comment: apply a `fade-in` animation, paired with a `move from left` animation in a single `AnimationSet` then execute it on the imageview in question.

Comment: The code you are providing does nothing with movement

Comment: @Shark can you provide me demo for this one?

Comment: let me explain you briefly. I need to start image animation from left with fading animation

Comment: No demos, just guidance; instantiate a translation animation, instantiate a "fade-in" animation, add them both to the same `AnimationSet`, execute the animationSet on the imageview.

Answer (score 3):

You are not provide Y coordinates for translation from left to right.This is only for translation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
     android:fromYDelta="0%p"
     android:toYDelta="100%p" />
```

Comment: let me explain you briefly. I need to start  image animation from left with fading animation

Answer (score 1):

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(1000, 0,0, 0);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
imgVIewName.startAnimation(animation);
imgViewName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```